# Algorithm for line breaking in monospace text

Tags: algorithms, text-processing

Is there a de facto standard algorithm for finding good places to put line breaks in a paragraph of text rendered in a monospace font (e.g. to a text console)?

The algorithm should aim to output lines of an equal length (which is given as an argument), inserting a variable number of spaces between each pair of adjacent words on the same line to produce a pleasing result.

The TeX algorithm [(*Breaking Paragraphs into Lines*, Knuth & Plass 1981](http://www.eprg.org/G53DOC/pdfs/knuth-plass-breaking.pdf)) is the go-to algorithm for fancy typesetting with variable-width fonts. It should be usable with fixed-width fonts by treating them like variable-width fonts, but is there a simpler algorithm tailor-made for monospace fonts?

Comment: Do you have an issue using that algorithm with a variable-width font where every character just happens to have the same width?

Comment: What are your requirements: maximum line size? equal sized lines for the whole para? do you neeed to block-justify the lines adding spaces?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par_(command)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s asking what algorithm to use

Comment: @jmoreno: asking for an algorithm is [not generally off-topic](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8213/is-what-algorithm-could-solve-my-problem-off-topic). In this case, the OP mentioned a complex algorithm for a specific problem and asks for a simpler one for an even more specific problem. That is IMHO focussed enough for making the question a good fit for this site, and I find it pretty ridicuolus that it already got 4 close votes.

Comment: ... it seems to me parts of the community here seem only to seek for reasons to close a question, instead of thinking about constructive ways to keep more of them open.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

- Scan forward in the text `X` characters.

  - While scanning forward if you encounter a line break, stop immediately and respect it.
  - While scanning forward count how many sections of white text there are as `white space sections`.
- If the current character is not white space, or a breaking character (such as -)

  - walk back and count as `white space to insert` till a whitespace or breaking character is encountered
  - if its a white space keep walk back till discovering a non-whitespace character, and subtract 1 from `white space sections`
- Return to the start of the line.
- walk forward printing each character

  - if the character is a whitespace keep printing till the first non whitespace character.
  - print `floor(white space to insert / white space sections)` spaces.
  - subtract that number from `white space to insert`
  - subtract 1 from `white space sections`
  - keep walking forward

This is a rough algorithm.

- You could count the total amount of whitespace and rejustify each time you encounter any amount of it. Just count each string of whitespace as a single section, and don't emit any when walking forward normally.
- I didn't account for the size of tab, depends on whether you want it to be aligned, or just a fixed size.
- You could add in auto justification for tab such that following lines align to it till a return is encountered. You will need to track the tab depth, and shorten the length of string walked forward.